# Vscode php debugger Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException: File does not exist at path

Tags: php, debugging, laravel-5.5, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I trying to debug a laravel code using vscode debugger, but I did, mark a break point on some controller line and then run debugger I encountered this

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException: File does not exist at path /mnt/c/projects/www/mycrateclub/storage/framework/cache/data/6f/cf/6fcf17e03636125ae681cea5779f3e9bfc88abbb
```

I running it in WSL with ubuntu 18.04 version and with php 7.2 installed.

I don't know what to do with, I'm stack.

Does anyone has experience the same?

I don't know where exactly the problem, laravel or vscode debugger, and I don't know either where to create issue, on vscode or laravel.

Comment: I am using windows 10 as operating system and WSL

Comment: I know that. I said that don't use C drive aka. `/mnt/c` as a project directory. Use Linux user home directory like `~` (spelled as tilde).

Comment: ahm wher should I do that?

Comment: I know about that, what I mean, where to set the path, what setting, so that the interaction between vscode and wsl would work and will found the right path for filesystem.php

Comment: Maybe it's a false positive. Look at this other Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255035/laravel-file-does-not-exist-at-path-cache

Comment: @Jeeba nope, its actually working now, just uncheck everything option, because i think vscode will try to go deeper beyond laravel code, I mean php builtin functions itself, not sure though, which cause vscode can't find the file to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off `Exceptions` in the Run/Debugging panel in the bottom left corner of your VS Code window. As [Jeeba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420804/jeeba) mentioned in the question comments, this error is a false positive. This is the only work-around I've found.

[VS Code Breakpoints screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCrWX.png)