# Laravel: File does not exist at path .../cache

Tags: laravel, caching

Full error:

```
Exception has occurred.
Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException: File does not exist at path D:\Projects\shop\back-end\storage\framework/cache/data/9c/1c/9c1c01dc3ac1445a500251fc34a15d3e75a849df
```

I tried php artisan cache:clear, php artisan config:cache. No result..

Comment: Do you have Storage directory in your project?

Comment: Take a look at the slashes....

Comment: @Eliott Yes, i have.

Comment: @demo I seen them, it's weird but it seems like that cache paths are stored somewhere. Dunno how to delete them (not cache in fact)

Comment: @GeorgeValentin maybe take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#after-installation . I have to admit that I cant replicate your failure.

Answer (score 8):

If you are accessing your cache store with `Cache::has()` this is expected behaviour. Deep down `Cache::has()` will try to access the anticipated location and will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the location is not present. [(Source)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L41)

In `Illuminate\Cache\FileStore` this exception is caught and converted to an empty payload. [(Source)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php#L174)

Some debugging tools, like XDebug, will halt on the `FileNotFoundException` which you can consider a false positive.

Comment: Yeah, they halt, it's annoying can anything be done about that? :)

Comment: Well, yes in VSCode if you uncheck `Everything` or specifically 'Exceptions` in the `Breakpoints` section of the Debug panel you won't see any breakpoints on any exception - it's not the best solution, but something that helps. I was unable to find a way to block only specific exceptions.

Comment: @Picard: Just wanted to say thanks. Your comment has saved me more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, VSCode breakpoints, I had "Everything" checked, however, I'll prob need to swing back after my project is done and figure what the heck is causing the issue.!